# Laravel backend validation preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?' using regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, backend

I have the following regex `(\bcherry\b)?(\bbanana\b)?/gi` if I simply test the regex it works however when I apply it to my backend validation in Laravel I get the a `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?'` error.

```
   public function rules()
   {
       return [
         'selection' => ['required', 'regex:(\bcherry\b)?(\bbanana\b)?/gi']
       ];
   }
```

I already tried escaping the '?' with a \ but then I get a `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\'` error

How do I write a regex that checks if the input is 'cherry' or 'banana' in Laravel?

Comment: I think you're missing the opening delimiter (`/`). You have a closing one: `/gi`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew You got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you were trying to match either a `banana` or `cherry`.

NOTE:

- PHP regex functions do not support `g` flag
- You need both leading and trailing regex delimiters.

Use

```
public function rules()
   {
       return [
         'selection' => ['required', 'regex:/\b(?:cherry|banana)\b/i']
       ];
   }
```